# Que estoy haciendo mal en este ejercicio PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

estoy realizando inner join de 3 tablas y no me funciona... con 2 tablas esta todo bien .. cuando añado la tercera tabla no me muestra nada.

```
 <?php 
        try{
            require_once('include/funciones/db_conexion.php');
            $sql = "SELECT `evento_id`, `nombre_evento`, `fecha_evento`, `hora_evento`, `nombre_invitado`";
            $sql .= "FROM `eventos`";
            $sql .= "INNER JOIN `categoria_evento`";
            $sql .= "ON eventos.id_cat_evento=categoria_evento.id_categoria";
            $sql .= "INNER JOIN `invitados`";
            $sql .= "ON eventos.id_inv=invitados.invitado_id";
            $resultado = $conn->query($sql);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $error = $e->getMessage();
        }
  ?>
  <?php while($eventos = $resultado->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC) ){
    ?>
    <pre>
    <?php var_dump($eventos); ?>
  </pre>
  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: imprimí el $sql antes de ejecutarlo y fijate si ves algo raro.

Comment: Como dice @Juan hay veces que al concatenar una linea con otra te genera errores al faltar un espacio por ej. Debes hacer esa prueba para descartar este tipo de errores de concatenación. También te recomiendo copiar y pegar el query obtenido en tu motor de base de datos para realizar pruebas fácilmente y al lograr obtener el resultado recién copiarlo a tu código.

Answer (score 1):

Mi sospecha es que al concatenar así no estás dejando espacios entre las palabras clave, de forma que to SQL final es:

```
SELECT `evento_id`, `nombre_evento`, `fecha_evento`, 
`hora_evento`, `nombre_invitado`FROM 
`eventos`INNER JOIN `categoria_evento`ON 
eventos.id_cat_evento=categoria_evento.id_categoriaINNER JOIN 
`invitados`ON eventos.id_inv=invitados.invitado_id
```

Funciona bien al poner solo el primer JOIN porque es en la fusión de la condición del `ON` del primer `JOIN` (en el nombre del campo) y la palabra clave `INNER` que todo se derrumba lentamente. El primer JOIN funciona porque tu código es el siguiente:

```
SELECT `evento_id`, `nombre_evento`, `fecha_evento`, 
`hora_evento`, `nombre_invitado`FROM 
`eventos`INNER JOIN `categoria_evento`ON 
eventos.id_cat_evento=categoria_evento.id_categoria
```

Debés tener cuidado con los espacios al concatenar comandos así. Modificá el código así:

```
<?php 
        try{
            require_once('include/funciones/db_conexion.php');
            $sql = "SELECT `evento_id`, `nombre_evento`, `fecha_evento`, `hora_evento`, `nombre_invitado` ";
            $sql .= "FROM `eventos` ";
            $sql .= "INNER JOIN `categoria_evento` ";
            $sql .= "ON eventos.id_cat_evento=categoria_evento.id_categoria ";
            $sql .= "INNER JOIN `invitados` ";
            $sql .= "ON eventos.id_inv=invitados.invitado_id ";
            $resultado = $conn->query($sql);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $error = $e->getMessage();
        }
  ?>
  <?php while($eventos = $resultado->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC) ){
    ?>
    <pre>
    <?php var_dump($eventos); ?>
  </pre>
  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias.. tenias razon .. los espacios tambien cuentan... ahora si me funciona..